# pop up form ajax request not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to add pop up contact form in my site and i take one example from internet and made some changes for it's sending mail and i made it for inserting data into database. so here my first file index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>A Slick Ajax Contact Form with jQuery and PHP</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var messageDelay = 2000; // How long to display status messages (in milliseconds)

        // Init the form once the document is ready
        $(init);

        // Initialize the form
        function init() {

            // Hide the form initially.
            // Make submitForm() the form's submit handler.
            // Position the form so it sits in the centre of the browser window.
            $('#contactForm').hide().submit(submitForm).addClass('positioned');

            // When the "Send us an email" link is clicked:
            // 1. Fade the content out
            // 2. Display the form
            // 3. Move focus to the first field
            // 4. Prevent the link being followed

            $('a[href="#contactForm"]').click(function() {
                $('#content').fadeTo('slow', .2);
                $('#contactForm').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                    $('#senderName').focus();
                })

                return false;
            });

            // When the "Cancel" button is clicked, close the form
            $('#cancel').click(function() {
                $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
                $('#content').fadeTo('slow', 1);
            });

            // When the "Escape" key is pressed, close the form
            $('#contactForm').keydown(function(event) {
                if (event.which == 27) {
                    $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
                    $('#content').fadeTo('slow', 1);
                }
            });

        }

        // Submit the form via Ajax
        function submitForm() {

            var contactForm = $(this);

            // Are all the fields filled in?
            if (!$('#senderName').val() || !$('#senderEmail').val() || !$('#ContactNo').val() || !$('#message').val()) {

                // No; display a warning message and return to the form
                $('#incompleteMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
                contactForm.fadeOut().delay(messageDelay).fadeIn();

            } else {

                // Yes; submit the form to the PHP script via Ajax
                $('#sendingMessage').fadeIn();
                contactForm.fadeOut();

                $.ajax({
                    url: contactForm.attr('action') + "?ajax=true",
                    type: contactForm.attr('method'),
                    data: contactForm.serialize(),
                    success: submitFinished
                });

            }

            // Prevent the default form submission occurring
            return false;
        }

        // Handle the Ajax response
        function submitFinished(response) {
            response = $.trim(response);
            $('#sendingMessage').fadeOut();

            if (response == "success") {

                // Form submitted successfully:
                // 1. Display the success message
                // 2. Clear the form fields
                // 3. Fade the content back in

                $('#successMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
                $('#senderName').val("");
                $('#senderEmail').val("");
                $('#ContactNo').val("");
                $('#message').val("");

                $('#content').delay(messageDelay + 500).fadeTo('slow', 1);

            } else {

                // Form submission failed: Display the failure message,
                // then redisplay the form
                $('#failureMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
                $('#contactForm').delay(messageDelay + 500).fadeIn();

            }

        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="content">
        <p style="padding-bottom: 50px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;"><a href="#contactForm">~ Send us an email ~</a></p>
    </div>

    <form id="contactForm" action="processForm.php" method="post">
        <h2>Send us an email...</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="senderName">Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="senderName" id="senderName" placeholder="Please type your name" required="required" maxlength="40" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="senderEmail">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="senderEmail" id="senderEmail" placeholder="Please type your email address" required="required" maxlength="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="ContactNo">Contact No</label>
                <input type="text" name="ContactNo" id="ContactNo" placeholder="Please type your contact no" required="required" maxlength="50" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="message" style="padding-top: .5em;">Your Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Please type your message" required="required" cols="80" rows="10" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="formButtons">
            <input type="submit" id="sendMessage" name="sendMessage" value="Send Email" />
            <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
        </div>
    </form>

    <div id="sendingMessage" class="statusMessage">
        <p>Sending your message. Please wait...</p>
    </div>

    <div id="successMessage" class="statusMessage">
        <p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="failureMessage" class="statusMessage">
        <p>There was a problem sending your message. Please try again.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="incompleteMessage" class="statusMessage">
        <p>Please complete all the fields in the form before sending.</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and other one is processForm.php is.

```
<?php

// Read the form values
$success     = false;
$senderName  = isset( $_POST['senderName'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderName'] ) : "";
$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['senderEmail'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['senderEmail'] ) : "";
$ContactNo   = isset( $_POST['ContactNo'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\ 0-9]/", "", $_POST['ContactNo'] ) : "";
$message     = $_POST['message'];

// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $contactNo && $message ) {

    include("config.php");
    $success = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `inquiry` (`name`, `contact`, `email`, `query`) VALUES ('$senderName', '$ContactNo', '$senderEmail', '$message')");

}

// Return an appropriate response to the browser
if ( isset($_GET["ajax"]) ) {

    echo $success ? "success" : "error";

} else { ?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Thanks!</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php if ( $success ) echo "<p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p>" ?>
        <?php if ( !$success ) echo "<p>There was a problem sending your message. Please try again.</p>" ?>
        <p>Click your browser's Back button to return to the page.</p>

    </body>
    </html>

<?php } ?>
```

problem is when i submit right for it display message "There was a problem sending your message. Please try again." please help me.

Comment: You've checked the database? Where you set $success to 'true'?

Comment: Try changing the $_GET to $_POST where you check if ajax is set, in the Php script, since the form is set to method post

Comment: i change it $_GET to $_POST. same problem.

Comment: have you checked weather the record is saved in DB?

Comment: are you sure the page is not reloading after submitting the form ?

Comment: So it seems that $success does not evaluate to true. Why don't you try to echo msyql_error() after mysql_query() and examine the response from the ajax call through tools like Firebug, or the Chrome Developer Toolbar. That would save a lot of guessing to us. Then you can at least say, if ( and what ) something is wrong with your database query.

Comment: My guess is the if condition is not evaluating to true and not executing hence `$success` always stays false.

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya any success?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you should change this line.

```
if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $contactNo && $message ) {
```

to

```
if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $ContactNo && $message ) {
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be related to using/accessing non existing variable `contactNo` since (quoting [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php))

> The variable name is case-sensitive.

And thus it should be changed respectively (the post variable name `$_POST['ContactNo']`  case depends on code that is not presented here, leaving as it is)

```
$contactNo = isset( $_POST['ContactNo'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\ 0-9]/", "", $_POST['ContactNo'] ) : "";
```

Finally, but not least - **stop using mysql extension since it is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and removed as of php 7.0.0**.

Answer (score 1):

You never set where `$success` is actually successful, which would be at this line after the query has executed:

```
$success=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `inquiry` (`name`, `contact`, `email`, `query`) VALUES ('$senderName', '$ContactNo', '$senderEmail', '$message')");
```

`$success` was actually `$query` initially.

That will return boolean `false` if the `query` fails, and a resource if it was true (I think), which will evaluate to `true`

Comment: i change $query to $success. same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried outputting all the variable values.

Print_r( 'sendName: ' . $senderName . 'SendEmail : ' . $senderEmail . 'Contact : '.$contactNo . ' Message :' . $message );
 Before conditional checking 
 if ( $senderName && $senderEmail &&
$contactNo && $message ) {

// then add this to know you actually connecting with db
echo 'now inserting sending ...' ;

//Then after insert, try check/get  mysql last error if one exist And echo it.

}

Answer (score 1):

PHP variables are case-sensitive.
In your case, $_POST['ContactNo'] is set in $ContactNo.

So the if-condition should be;

```
if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $ContactNo && $message ) {
```